# Unable to access companion object used in kotlin class after enabling proguard

Tags: kotlin, proguard

I have a Kotlin class with some variables in companion object. After enabling proguard, The variables are not getting accessed.

```
class Test{    
    ......    
    companion object {    
        const val USER_NAME = "user_name"    
        .....    
  }    
  .....    
}
```

Proguard rules include:-

```
-keep class kotlin.** { *; }    
-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }    
-dontwarn kotlin.**    
-keepclassmembers class **$WhenMappings {    
    <fields>;    
}    
-keepclassmembers class kotlin.Metadata {    
    public <fields>;    
    public <methods>;    
}    

-keepclassmembers class * {    
    static final % *;    
    static final java.lang.String *;    
}
```

Comment: Are you getting a runtime error, if so please post the error and stack trace as part of your question.

Comment: No it is not run time error, It is a compile time error. While trying to build my project I am getting error as Unresolved reference : USER_NAME.

Comment: Would annotating with `@JvmStatic`  not help in this case?

Comment: I have tried adding that but I guess we need to add some rule in proguard related to @JvmStatic in this case. I tried finding it but couldn't.

Comment: What does the code look like that is referencing the variable, and what is the exact error message from the compiler, these are important details to add to your question.

Comment: The problem is resolved by using `@Keep` before the companion object.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Problem resolved using `@Keep` before companion object

```
class Test{    
    ......    
    @Keep companion object {    
        const val USER_NAME = "user_name"    
        .....    
  }    
  .....    
}
```

Comment: I also needed to add @Keep above the class, adding it just for the companion object did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer uses the `@Keep` annotation. If that works for you, then great, but in our case it didn't make a difference.

For anyone else in the same boat, here's the solution that worked for us (add to your proguard rules):

```
-keepclassmembers class com.example.some.package.SomeClass {
    public static ** Companion;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

After many struggles with it the thing that worked best for me is:

```
 -keep class <class>$Companion { *; }
```

no annotations needed.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem, there was a function in the companion object that was not being accessed after enabling proguard.

`@Keep` didn't work for me, after a lot of struggle. I found the solution.

Just add `@JvmStatic` annotation to the function inside the companion object.
And you are good to go.